# Styling the stacked column highchart datalabels individually

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been tasked to individually style each one of highcharts' stacked barchart data labels: the ones I am referring to is the 3,2,5 in the first chart, the 4,2,3 in the second and so on. To style these all together is easy, as seen in the documentation/fiddle. How do I style them individually?

The fiddle has the code for the styling of all of them:

```
 dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
```

Here is the JS Fiddle as per their documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/3ak4ckuq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "useHTML: true" on the datalabels. Then you can access the individual datalabel element of any point and modify the styles or add classes etc:

```
_.each(chart.series, function(serie) {
    _.each(serie.data, function(point) {

        var spanElement = point.dataLabel.div.firstChild;
        spanElement.style.fontSize = _.sample(randomFontSizes);
        spanElement.style.color = _.sample(randomColors);
        spanElement.classList.add("custom-class");
    });
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ak4ckuq/6/